# How to cast to integer and don't lose precision

Tags: java, int

I have a double value which is very close to 1. How can I cast it to 1 ?
I do this

```
 double myValue = 0.9999;
 double a = Math.round(myValue);
 int intValue = (int)a;
```

But it return 1 even if myValue is in the the range [0.5 , 1], so I lose precision. I want it return 1 only if myValuse is so close to 1 (exp : 0.999) and it should not return 1 when myValue is 0.6 for example.

Thank u for ur help

Comment: what else would you expect?

Comment: You explained what you don't want, but not what you want...

Comment: Which integer would you like 0.6 to be rounded to?

Comment: I want 0.6 to be rounded to 0.  But I know that Math.round() function doesn't work like that :(

Comment: @amani92 How about 0.7? 0.8? 0.9? 0.95? 0.99? What is the rule?

Comment: for 0.7, 0.8, 0.9 it should return 0

Comment: Perhaps you could do something like `Math.round(myValue - 0.3)` - this will round 0.8 upwards, but smaller numbers downwards.  Or change the `0.3` to some more suitable number.

Comment: @amani92 So: what is the rule? Anything below 0.9 rounded to 0 and anything between 0.9 and 1 rounded to 1?

Comment: `int intValue = (myValue - 0.9) > 0 ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: I keep trying to convince myself that that will work, rather than my complicated solution below. I *think* it will... Maybe flesh it out (with tests proving it works across a range of values) and post as an answer?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't believe in answering a question _before_ the querent has made their requirements clear.  In this case, it's not the slightest bit clear to me exactly what amani92 wants - particularly when it comes to larger numbers.  So I'm trying to prompt her so that she'll clarify her requirements.  If she doesn't do so, she won't get an answer from me.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: Fair enough, though it seems clear enough to me. Instead of getting 1 at .5 and up, he/she wants 1 at [insert value here] and up. (**Why** is another question entirely. :-) )

Comment: OK, but what should 1.99 be rounded to?  How about -0.99?  -1.01?  So many questions.  @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: Indeed, good point. :-) I've made unquestioned assumptions there, which could easily be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, what I really ought to do is VTC it as UWYA, but that seems unkind.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: VTC can be retracted when clarification is added. You're right, it's unclear. I just didn't question my own subconscious assumptions.

Answer (score 6):

[`Math.round`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) is specifically designed to do that. If you want to do something different, you'll have to code it yourself.

For instance, if you want `.8` and higher to round to 1 instead of `.5` and higher *(see note below about negative numbers)*:

```
double myValue = 0.9999;
int base = (int)Math.floor(myValue);
double remainder = myValue - base;
int intValue = remainder >= .8 ? base + 1 : base;
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/FD5LCz)

There, we:

1. Get the whole number part (`Math.floor`) into base, *truncating* the fractional portion
2. Get just the fractional portion into `remainder`
3. Add one to `base` if the fractional portion is `>=` .8

Obviously, you'll have to choose the point at which you round up, since you want something other than .5.

If you want to handle negative numbers, it's more complicated, since [`Math.floor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-) will always go toward positive infinity. So you may have to branch on the sign of `myValue` and use [`Math.ceil`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-) instead when negative (and adjust the `myValue - base` accordingly). And then there's the entire question of whether the same kind of cutoff applies, or is it symmetrical? Should that cutoff be -0.8 or -0.2? I leave handling negative values in the manner you want as an exercise for you...

That said, this feels more complicated than it should be. Perhaps something like [what's described in Dawood ibn Kareem's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369201/how-to-cast-to-integer-and-dont-lose-precision/45369318#comment77699419_45369201) would work for what you're trying to do. (May have to be `+ 0.3` rather than `- 0.3` when handling negatives. Or not.)

Comment: Thank u @T.J. Crowder but i'm loking for a method more simple with precision

Comment: @amani92: Good luck with that. The requirement is unusual, and the above isn't all that complicated. (But again: Depending on what your actual requirements are, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369201/how-to-cast-to-integer-and-dont-lose-precision/45369318#comment77699419_45369201) may provide a simpler way.) It's not at all clear why you think 0.9 should become 0 but 0.99 should become 1. It's certainly not a more "precise" result. Quite the opposite. There's a reason why this is not part of the standard API. It doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
final double threshold = 0.0001;
if (Math.abs(a - 1) < threshold)
    intValue = 1;
else
    intValue = 0;
```

This will set `intValue` to `1` when `a` is "close enough to 1" (ie. within `threshold` of 1), and will set `intValue` to `0` otherwise (assuming you want it rounded to `0` if it's not within the threshold).

You can adjust the value of the threshold to tighten or loosen the range around 1 that it'll handle.

Alternatively, if you want to round to `1` if it's just above a given value, you can do eg.:

```
if (a >= 0.9999)
    intValue = 1;
else
    intValue = 0;
```